# How do I add Lua to a C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lua

1) How do I add Lua to a C++ project in microsoft visual studio 2017. I have downloaded all the Lua files but I need to Add Lua to the project properties.
2) Whats the main difference between C++ and C
3) Which language is best to create a GUI, Lua, C, C# or C++.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `#include <lua.hpp>`

Comment: The one title doesn’t represent the second and third questions. They are also too broad and/or opinionated, or answered elsewhere. Google first! Then post single, focused questions.

Comment: Please read/do basic programming tutorials, these are Computer science 101 questions.Fox example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/

Answer (score 1):

Questions 2) and 3) aren't really stackoverflow questions. As for 1), the book Programming in Lua does a pretty good job at explaining that, at least the basics. From there you can just read the reference and see what functions you may find useful.